# Django text in SmallIntegerField results in a KeyError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a simple html form using models.Model in models.py, ModelForm in forms.py and oldschool Django templates (nothing fancy)

If a user inputs text in a number field and submits the form, the server returns a `KeyError`

Example: The following field 'height':

```
class DataRegistryPart2(models.Model):
    height = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Will be displayed as a html input in the template:

```
<input id="id_height" name="height" type="number">
```

Im using custom validation in forms.py:

```
...
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(CreatePatient, self).clean()
    height = cleaned_data["height"] # <-- This is where the KeyError happens!
```

If a user enters **text** or a **decimal** number in the input field and submits the html form, Django returns a KeyError.

How can I prevent this from happening (without using try/catch).

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter non-valid values into a field, that field is by definition not clean, so it will not be present in `cleaned_data`; hence the KeyError.

Unless you need this value to do some validation in combination with another field, you should do whatever you are doing in the specific `clean_height` method; this will only be called if the value passes the built-in field validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It sounds like its a really bad idea to use the clean function at all then - its very likely that a user enters non-valid data into a form which crashes the system.
Perhaps Im misunderstanding something, but I find it hard to see the usage of the clean function now. Perhaps you can elaborate?

Comment: No not really. As I say, it's for doing validations across more than one field; in this case, you can use `cleaned_data.get('fieldname')` to access a potentially missing value without triggering a KeyError.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.